# Prevent blur/focusout event only if user clicks a certain element

Tags: jquery, onclick

Here is the situation: I have an editable text area. When the user selects the text area and makes changes, a save button appears. When they click out of the text area, the button disappears and if they made changes, they get an alert asking if they want to save changes. However, if they click the save button, I don't want the alert to appear, and I want the save function to fire via an onclick event attached to the button. The following code gives the alert even when they press the save button, and doesn't run the save button's onClick code. What is the best way to make this work?
Thanks!!!

```
$(".userNoteTextArea").focus(function() {
$("#noteTextAreaButtons").show();
}).bind('focusout', function(event) {
if (!$(event.target).is('#noteTextAreaButtons')) {
    $("#noteTextAreaButtons").hide();
    if (stillNotSaved == true) {
        if (confirm("Save changes?")) { //Ok button pressed...
            storeUserNote2(); //save note
        }
    }
}
});
```

Save button code:

```
<div id="noteTextAreaButtons" style="display:none;"><input id="saveUserNoteButton" class="buttonAutoWide opaque" type="button" value="Saved" onClick="storeUserNote2(); this.value='Saved'"/></div>
```

Edit: This file available to view at http://gospelriver.com/favhymns/favhymns_temp.html. Click the My Songs button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what I may end up doing is forget the whole button approach and just use the auto prompt when they exit the text area after making changes-- OK = save, Cancel = discard changes.

Answer (score 0):

Include a new function as below

```
function SaveClicked(){
    stillNotSaved = false;
    storeUserNote2(); 
    this.value='Saved';
}
```

I hope the `stillNotSaved` variable you have used is a `global variable` in js. And modify your `input` code as below.

```
<input id="saveUserNoteButton" class="buttonAutoWide opaque" 
            type="button" value="Saved" onClick="SaveClicked();"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. stillNotSaved is indeed global. I tried your suggestion and it results in the same issues. I also tried `if (!$(event.target).is('#saveUserNoteButton'))` and that doesn't work... any other ideas?